# Using Julia in Python

Tags: python-3.x, julia

I am trying to call the PowerModels julia package in python. I have successfully downloaded julia, installed the PowerModels package (ran a successful test in julia), set the ENV["PYTHON"] to "C:/Users/user1/Anaconda3/python.exe", added the PyCall package. Added the bin file of julia to the system variable. Then installed pyjulia using Anaconda.

When I open the python.exe file located in "C:/Users/user1/Anaconda3/python.exe" I can successfully call from julia.PowerModels import run_ac_opf. However when I try to do it from Spyder, Jupyter, or python in Anaconda base I get an error that the procedure entry point cannot be located in the dynamic link library LLVM.dll of julia.

I am using windows 10, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple installations (thus multiple `python.exe` files) it is good to check that they are all using the same `python.exe` interpreter.

I would try to include the directory containing julia's LLVM.dll in the windows environment variable PATH.